# How to apply firebase database security rules from swift code

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have added firebase security rules with authentication turned on. i have given write access based on key..

[image]

> Firebase rules templet

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
        ".write": "auth.uid == \"jack\""
    }
  }
}
```

Now i am looking toward adding that rules in swift code

```
  var ref: DatabaseReference!
  ref = Database.database().reference()

Setting data as

ref.child("users/jack").setValue("jack")..// Something here to change.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set the user's UID from your Swift code. After all, if you could do that, anyone could do it by taking your configuration data and running whatever code they want against your database too.

The only way to set the UID for a user is if you [create a custom authentication provider](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens), which can only be done from a trusted environment such as your development machine, a server you control, or Cloud Functions.

---

To secure your database instead, sign in to Firebase Authentication in your Swift code (for example with [anonymous authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/anonymous-auth)), then log the UID, and use that instead of `jack` in your security rules.

Comment: Thanks.. : ) i just posted code below. please check

Answer (score 0):

As per suggestion of Frank.

I have done it as

> pod 'Firebase/Auth'

```
 import FirebaseAuth

   Auth.auth().signInAnonymously { authDataResult, errorObj in
   if let error = errorObj {
          print("Sign in failed:", error.localizedDescription)
   } else {
     guard let userIdRecieved = authDataResult?.user.uid else {return}
            ref.child("users/\(userIdRecieved)/...
```